# How Jackson serialize none by default？

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

When I use spring mvc.I want got json string.But got a problem.

I hava a class User:

```
public class User {
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        private boolean enabled = true;
        private DateTime registeTime;
        private String ip;
        private DateTime loginTime;
        private DateTime logoutTime;
        private String loginIp;
        private DateTime lastLogoutTime;
        private int passwordExpiredDays = -1;
        private DateTime passwordChangeTime;
        private boolean loginAtSameTime = false;
        private int loginAttempt = 0;
        private int status = 0;
        private String problem;
        private String solution;
}
```

I want get json like:

```
{"username":"a","ip":"127.0.0.1"}
```

now,I use:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"password","accountNonExpired", 
"accountNonLocked","credentialsNonExpired", "enabled", "registeTime", 
"loginTime", "logoutTime", "passwordExpiredDays", "passwordChangeTime", 
"loginAtSameTime", "loginAttempt", "status", "problem", "solution"})
public class User {
        ...
}
```

But!!!This very complex.Can I got a way to solve it？Such as:

```
@JsonInclude("Annotation")
public class User {
    @JsonInclude
    private String username;
    ...
    @JsonInclude
    private String ip;
    ...
}
```

or

```
@JsonIncludeProperties(value={"username", "ip"})
public class User {
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `@JsonIgnore`  annotation at the field level to avoid it during serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is mark the fields you want with `@JsonProperty`. For example:

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty
    private String username;
    ...
    @JsonProperty
    private String ip;
    ...
}
```